# Internet Video Playback Choppy Ubuntu 20.04.3 LST

Tags: gnome, firefox, video, yoga-2

Dual booting Ubuntu 20.04.3 LST and Windows. Ubuntu seems to work perfectly, apart from internet videos are choppy/juttery (framerate is consistent apart from momentary drops to very low framerates)

I have tried all permutations of the following: hardware acceleration on/off; chromium/firefox (also all attempted in safe mode); XORG/Wayland; Gnome/XFCE/Plasma;

Video works perfectly in windows. Also offline videos seem to work very well on ubuntu.

I have not installed any power saving features.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Stats below:

Lenovo Yoga710;
8gb memory;
Intel Core i7-6500U CPu @ 2.50Ghz x 4;
Mesa Intel HD Graphics 520 (SKL GT2);
256.1GB SSD;
OS 64 bit;
Gnome version 3.36.8;
Windowing System: X11;

Comment: Video playback on internet browsers is not hardware accelerated on Linux whereas it is on Windows. The local videos are played with media players, like `vlc` for example that do use hardware acceleration.

Comment: Ahh that's disappointing! I've used linux a huge amount for server management and was hoping to cross over for desktop use (and loved it), but if youtube videos are unwatchable, somewhat of a deal breaker.

thank you for your reply!

Comment: Yes, it is a big problem indeed and the ones who are responsible for this are the companies that make the browsers, not Linux itself. They insist on not activating hardware accelerated video decoding because it causes *browser instability* according to them. If you google this subject though, you can find articles that will help you activate it yourself but it is not 100% certain that it's going to work on your GPU. You have to do some experiments.

Comment: Ah I'll see if I can get that going! Although, investigating, I did notice two oddities 1) firefox video, at the moment, uses a lot of my intel gpu under the heading "render" rather than "video" (leaving gnome Activities stuttery)  2) vlc/mpv exhibit similar problems to firefox/chromium, just to a much much lesser extent.

I'm going to follow a firefox hardware acceleration set up guide and see what happens.

Once again, thanks for all the advice!